# extracting substring from string using pointers in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, buffer

I currently am trying to extract a substring within a bufferline. The goal is to parse the string by whitespace and symbols to compile later. The line I'm trying to parse is the first line of my file.

```
void append(char* s, char c)
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    s[len] = c;
    s[len+1] = '\0';
}

int main(void){    
    char str[] = "program example(input, output);";

    char *f = str;
    char *b = str;

    char token[10];

    if(*f != '\0'){
        while (*f != ' ')
        {
            append(token,*f);
            f++;
        }
        f++;
        printf("%s",token);
        token[9] = '\0';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Am I clearing the token string wrong? The code only returns:

```
program
```

but it should return

```
program
example(input,
output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things fundamentally wrong with your code (possibility of buffer overflow 
 in your append() function, etc). I have changed just enough to allow the code to produce the desired result, to my understanding.

```
int main(void){    
    char str[] = "program example(input, output);";

    char *f = str;

    char *token=(char *)malloc((strlen(str)+1)*sizeof(char));
    char *b = token;

    while(*f != '\0'){
        while (*f && *f != ' ')
        {
            *b++=*f;
            f++;
        }
        if(*f) f++;
        *b=0;
        b=token;
        printf("%s\n",token);
    }
    free(token);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./a.out 
program
example(input,
output);
```

Comment: Thank you! My goal is to separate the each token. This should get me on the right track now.